# Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object throws at /resource/chartjs:6:15548 | Salesforce Lightning and Chart.Js

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, charts

I am encountering below issue while working with chart.js library in salesforce lightning component . I see the below error when i hover or click on the doughnut chart generated . Any help is greatly appreciated .Thanks!

*Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object throws at /resource/chartjs:6:15548*

**Component**

---

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/chartjs" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />   
 <div aura:id="progressDiv" class="progressContent">
<canvas aura:id="canvasChart" width="80" height="90"  />
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
 var bg = component.find('canvasChart');
 var ctx  = bg.getElement().getContext('2d');

  var config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                20,
                20,
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#ffffff",

            ],
            label: 'Dataset 1'
        }],
        labels: [
            "RED","GREEN"

        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
            cutoutPercentage:80,

        title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
        },
        animation: {
            animateScale: true,
            animateRotate: true
        }
    }
};
var doughnout = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Answer (score 2):

The likely fix for this is being prepared for release on or near 10/18. I'd like to verify it before then though to eliminate any cycle time if I am wrong. What specific version of chartjs are you using?

Comment: thanks for your reply . I am using the latest Version 2.3.0. Can you guide me  if there is  any work around before that date or any other chart libraries which you may be aware of that work seamlessly with Lightning ?

Comment: For now deactivate Locker Service in your org under Setup | Critical Updates and keep using ChartJS - things should be in much better shape after the fix I mentioned above goes out next week.